# Excel 2021 VBA Mass Email - Capturing cell values in html code

Tags: html, excel, email, edit, mass

I'm creating a database using Excel 2021.  One aspect is to be able to email members from this database.  I know the vba code to do this.

My issue is when users will write the email they won't have access to or know how to use vb code.  So I'm trying to do a "mini html editor" where it can integrate one off cell values. How would I get this to: catch cell values; respect date formatting; format email addresses as links. I need this to be where the average user can get to it, so it can't be done in teh vba code.  I just want teh code to catch the data in that cell as strBody.

I've figured some out, but not all.

I appreciate any and all help given.

[image]